# Why does sql update creates a new row in my database (C#)?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on my own asp.net mvc project and i have a little problem with updating my mysql database.

I have a table in my database with the following columns: (account, firstname, lastname, birthday, phonenumber, profilepicture) all of them are varchar columns and the table is called 'usersprofile'.

Here you can see one row in the table.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnQMf.jpg

Everytime i try to update any column i get a duplicate primary key error for the primary key column 'cause the update command tries to create a new line.

Here you can see my C# code for the update:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDJiA.jpg

It was a little bit more complex but it didn't work so i decided to make it more simpler by changing it so i can test if it works or not. If i'm correct i used the syntax well and i really have no idea why the update method wants to create a new row in my database.

Do u have any idea?

Comment: Please do not post images of code. They are unreadable and it is not possible to copy & paste code from an image to test it

Comment: Are you sure its not calling the insert?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I would suggest you to debug your code and set breakpoints to verify your assumption that the code executed is the update.

Comment: For some reason the stack trace refers to my insert method but i don't call the insert method here. When i click on the specific button on the website it calls the code linked above.

Comment: @DánielFoltán well clearly it is calling the insert, you havent included the stack trace so if it is calling insert you need to track down why and stop it :)

Comment: Oh...I was lame. Really really lame. I created my manage view by copying my previous view and the form was redirected to another controller's action method which called the insert.

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleague had the same issue, The Id wasn't auto-generated. You could add that to the Id property in your class. (DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]).

To manually tackle this(Crude) => Specify the previous Id number to be sure it's updated.

But it's certain you're trying to insert into the table.